# Windows service fails to open the connection

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, odbc

My C# Windows service sends emails automatically. Before sending I need to convert and attach my report as a PDF. I get an exception on the line below when I try to export the PDF:

```
cr.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, savePath);
```

> Failed to open the connection (ODBC)

The same code functions properly in a windows form application. How can I resolve this?

```
public void GenerateReport(string rptpath, int no)
{
  try
  {
    string savePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Savepath"];
    ReportDocument cr = new ReportDocument();

    cr.Load(rptpath);

    TableLogOnInfo logInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    Tables crTables = cr.Database.Tables;

    foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
    {
      logInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
      logInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SunVue";
      logInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SunVue";
      logInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "sa";
      logInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
      crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(logInfo);

      DateTime enddate = DateTime.Today;
      DateTime startdate = enddate.AddDays(-7);
      string reportFormula = string.Empty;

      if (no == 201)
      {
        cr.SetParameterValue("DateRange",startdate.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")
                                + " to " + enddate.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"));

        reportFormula = "{spilInvNum.OrderDate} in DateTime ("
                        + startdate.Year.ToString() + ","
                        + startdate.Month.ToString() + "," +
                        + startdate.Day.ToString() + ", 00, 00, 00) to DateTime ("
                        + enddate.Year.ToString() + ","
                        + enddate.Month.ToString() + ","
                        + enddate.Day.ToString() + ", 00, 00, 00)";

        //reportFormula = "{spilInvNum.OrderDate} in Date(" + startdate.Year.ToString() + "," + startdate.Month.ToString() + "," + startdate.Day.ToString() + ") " + " to DateTime (" + enddate.Year.ToString() + "," + enddate.Month.ToString() + "," + enddate.Day.ToString() + ") " + " and {spilInvNum.DocState} <> 6 and {spilInvNum.DocType} = 4 and {spilInvNum.AccountID} <> 2592";
        cr.RecordSelectionFormula = reportFormula;
      }
      cr.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, savePath);
      WriteToFile(savePath);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: check the file `savePath` permission.

Answer (score 0):

How you set up your connection in OBDC.

1. Did you try to test the connection upon stablishing on ODBC?
2. How did you do to use connection, in report wizard? using OBDC created?
   -upon connecting on CR wizard you should be promted if you have a false connection created.

Comment: check your odbc connection first